# How to access Doctrine simple query "findall" results

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mariadb

This is my first "findall" simple query.  The purpose is to randomly select 1 record and then echo the value of "reference" (a field in the BibleAnagrams table).  I am using PHP's array_rand for the random selection.  What I need help with is how to access the value of 'reference' from the resulting arrany_rand() array.

```
$Bible_anagram_reference = NULL;

/**
* @var \AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams $result
*/
$result = $this->getDoctrineEntityManager()
    ->getRepository(get_class($this->getEntityBibleAnagrams()))
    ->findAll();

if (is_array($result) && count($result) > 0) {
    /**
    * @var \AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams $value
    */
    $value = array_rand($result, 1);
    echo "Bible Ananagram: " . $result[$value]['reference'] . "\r\n";

    exit;
}
```

The randomly selected record gives the result:

```
$result = Array
    (
    [0] => AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams Object
        (
        [reference:AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams:private] => 1
        [languageIso:AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams:private] => en
        [bibleAnagramWord:AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams:private] => Love
        [word1:AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams:private] => Like
        [word2:AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams:private] => Openness
        [word3:AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams:private] => Venerate
        [word4:AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams:private] => Enjoyment
    )
);
```

When I use

```
echo "Bible Ananagram: " . $result[$value]['reference'] . "\r\n";
```

I receive the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\BibleAnagrams as array
```

When I use

```
echo "Bible Ananagram: " . $result[$value]->reference . "\r\n";
```

I receive the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property
```

If there are more details you need to help me please advice what these are.  Many thanks, Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results returned by `findAll()` function is an array of Doctrine Entities. To access the values in the results you need to use getter methods. Loop through results and print the values like this:

```
$results = $this->getDoctrineEntityManager()
    ->getRepository(get_class($this->getEntityBibleAnagrams()))
    ->findAll();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->getLike()."<br />";
    echo $result->getOpenness()."<br />";
    echo $result->getVenerate()."<br />";
    echo $result->getEnjoyment()."<br />";
}
```

For this to work, make sure you have `getLike()`, `getOpenness()`, `getVenerate()`, `getEnjoyment()` or any other methods defined in your entity which return required parameters. An example definition of `getOpenness()` function:

```
public function getOpenness()
{
    return $this->Openness;
}
```